# Наибольшее из заданных элементов

Tags: c, алгоритм

Учусь в универе на 1 курсе. дали задание на языке Си написать программу, которая принимает в качестве входных данных ряд чисел, а затем печатает наибольшее из них. Программа ожидает новые числа пока не будет введён 0 или отрицательное число. Думаю нужно использовать массивы но как это реализовать не знаю.

Comment: Можно и без массива. Так даже легче будет.

Answer (score 2):

Если решать без массива, то надо каждое введённое число сравнивать с нулём: если оно строго больше нуля и первое, то записываем его в переменную, которая будет содержать наибольшее число. Каждое следующее число сравниваем с этой переменной: если переменная больше этого числа, то оставляем её без изменений, иначе записываем в неё это число. В конце просто выводим эту переменную.

Comment: Чтобы не писать лишнюю логику по обработке первого значения, лучше инициализировать переменную значением заведомо меньшим любого значения на входе. В данной задаче достаточно нуля)